# Serializar números en coma flotante

Tags: c++, serialización, coma-flotante

Transferir datos en coma flotante entre diferentes plataformas es muy incómodo, no todas las plataformas siguen el [IEEE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante) o no disponen de todas las precisiones existentes (simple, doble, extendida).

Según el [complemento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos), [redondeo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redondeo) o tratamiento de [valores especiales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#NaN_en_coma_flotante) la codificación del número puede variar mucho incluso entre plataformas similares.

Así que he pensado que tal vez lo más conveniente sea codificar el número en origen usando algún formato portable y descodificarlo en destino siguiendo las reglas y características de la plataforma de destino<sup>1</sup>.

Se me ocurren dos maneras de hacer esto:

1. Pasar el número a texto:

   - Así `3,14159265358979323846` pasaría a `"3,14159265358979323846"`<sup>2</sup>.
2. Codificar el número decimal en valores no decimales:

   - Así `0,1` pasaría a `1` y `-1` ya que 0,1 = 1 * 10<sup>-1</sup>.

La primera opción provoca que aumente el tamaño del número a codificar, si estuviese tratando un `double` de 8 bytes pasaría a ocupar más del doble (22 bytes), mucho peor el caso si el número fuese un `float` de 4 bytes.

Pese a que el aumento de memoria usada al codificar en la primera opción es asumible, quisiera intentar la segunda opción y pensé que la función [`std::frexp`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp) serviría para mis fines, pero no entiendo cómo funciona, por ejemplo para 0,1 esperaba un exponente de -1 pero obtengo -3:

```
int exp{};
auto value = std::frexp(.1f, &exp);
std::cout << "fraccion " << value << " exponente " << exp << '\n';
```

Muestra:

> ```
> fraccion 0.8 exponente -3
> ```

Sin duda estoy entendiendo mal cómo funciona `std::frexp`, además tampoco es una solución completamente efectiva con números irracionales pero esperaba poder codificar π como 3141592653 * 10<sup>-9</sup> aún con la pérdida de precisión<sup>3</sup>.

Así que en resumen, mi pregunta sería:

- ¿De qué manera puedo codificar un número en coma flotante en dos enteros (base y exponente) para serializar (y deserializar) estos números de manera portable?

Asumimos que ya dispongo de una manera de codificar números enteros de manera portable.

---

<sup>1</sup>Y tratando de manera especial los valores especiales.

<sup>2</sup>Usar punto `.` o coma `,` como separador decimal es indiferente siempre y cuando se use el mismo símbolo al codificar y decodificar.

<sup>3</sup>Usando un `unsigned long long` para la base aumentaría la precisión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicación de `frexp`:

> Breaks the floating point number x into its binary significand (a floating point with an absolute value between 0.5(included) and 1.0(excluded)) and an integral exponent for 2.

Es decir, 1.0 no está incluído en el posible rango de valores para la fracción. No me he puesto a investigar la algorítmia que tiene por detrás la función, por lo que tampoco podría garantizar que el resultado obtenido fuese el mismo en diferentes arquitecturas.

Buscar un mecanismo específico sería algo a pensar con tranquilidad (diferentes tamaños para exponente y mantisa, diferente mecanismo de normalización, etc), quizás elegir un formato neutro y convertir todas las representaciones a dicho formato... pero es una opción que requiere bastante tiempo de desarrollo.

Muchos protocolos de red convierten a string por defecto para atajar el problema y no suelen tener muchos problemas de rendimiento. Yo creo que es la opción a elegir salvo que aparezca un requisito que imposibilite esta opción.

Comment: Según [este artículo](http://www.dursi.ca/scientific-data-shouldnt-be-written-in-text/) escribir números en coma flotante en archivos tiene un rendimiento casi 500 veces peor que hacerlo en binario. [Este otro artículo](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/float-precision-revisited-nine-digit-float-portability/) (mencionado en el primero) por otro lado, aconseja esa aproximación... ambos usan la codificación en string para diferentes objetivos, por desgracia mi objetivo está más próximo al del autor del primer artículo.

Comment: De momento he hecho [unas pruebas](http://ideone.com/EyI05a) que pintan bien; intentaré librarme de las alarmas de *narrowing* y probarlo en diferentes arquitecturas.

Comment: Piensa que Json, protocol buffers y compañía usan una serialización a string cuando podían haber optado por una serialización binaria... y si empresas tipo Google optan por este tipo de soluciones es que sus razones tienen...

Comment: Uno de los problemas que te puedes encontrar es que la gran heterogeneidad existente en los diferentes formatos de coma flotante te pueden obligar a realizar muchas operaciones para conseguir una secuencia binaria realmente portable... y luego ese código habría que mantenerlo... si todo ese coste supera los inconvenientes ocasionados por la pérdida de rendimiento entonces no hay mucho que discutir